# Accessing Magento API with Java : Procedure ххх not present

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy, magento

I need to build Special Java Api to wrap Magento Api. After struggling with several Magento bugs, I am finally able to login and get session id; but any method I call leads me to an error. The error is:

```
Procedure '*procedure name*' not present
```

I generated Java code from wsdl using Eclipse build in plugin and wsdl located at my local server: *http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1*.

The example of java code I use:

```
    Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeProxy proxy = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeProxy(
            "http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/");
    String sessionId = proxy.login("magentobot", "123456");
    System.out.println("Session: " + sessionId);
    CatalogProductEntity[] products = proxy.catalogProductList(sessionId, new Filters(), "");
```

And here is the exception I got:

```
Session: 12abdaf054fb7100b6c5d84ab8cb8311
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Procedure 'catalogProductList' not present
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Procedure 'catalogProductList' not present
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at Magento.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBindingStub.catalogProductList(Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBindingStub.java:3104)
    at Magento.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeProxy.catalogProductList(Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeProxy.java:260)
    at Main2.main(Main2.java:14)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:Dacer
```

Here is the link to the official documentation: [Magento product API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#catalog_product.list)
It says that the method is called *catalog_product.list*

The php code for the API works fine:

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('magentobot', '123456');
$filters = array();
$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));

var_dump($products);
?>
```

I will be glad to any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used the API from java before, but looking over your code example, you said you generated code using the v2 WSDL (which is supposed to have better Java/.NET SOAP support), but in your code sample you're pointing at the v1 URL

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/
```

I would assume you want your code sample pointing at

```
http://magento1point4.dev/index.php/api/v2_soap
```

but again, not a big Java (or SOAP, for that matter) guy, so appologies if there's something obvious I'm missing here.